# ¿Cómo puedo encerrar un resultado entre " para que me lo tome como un parametro de una formula? En R

Tags: r

Sucede que estoy trabajando con `dygraph()` para un grafico dinámico, además le puse `dyRangeSelector()` para que me aparezca el rango de fechas abajo del grafico. Esta ultima función, tiene la opción de que por defecto te aparezca graficado un rango de fechas y me gustaría que de forma automática aparecieran los últimos 12 meses, pero no se como. Actualmente la función que tengo para los rangos es esta:

```
dyRangeSelector(dateWindow = c("2018-04-01", "2019-03-01"))
```

Pues son los últimos 12 meses que tengo en la base, pero conforme se van agregando datos los meses van cambiando y para no estar cambiando el script me gustaría hacer la función para que automáticamente me agarre los últimos 12 meses ingresados. ¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo?

Con `x[(nrow(x)-12),1]` y `x[nrow(x),1]` puedo obtener el rango para los últimos 12 meses, pero al ingresarlo a la formula me da error pues no me lo toma como como si yo escribiera "2018-04-01".

Gracias de antemano cualquier ayuda que me puedan dar.

La formula completa es esta:

```
base1=ts(frequency = 12, start = c(2015, 10),read_excel("C:/.../1.xlsx", sheet = "Hoja1")[,2])
x=read_excel("C:/.../1.xlsx", sheet = "Hoja1")

dygraph(base1) %>%
   dyAxis("y", label = "Y", valueRange = c(0, 110)) %>%
   dyAxis("x", label = "X", drawGrid = FALSE) %>% 
   dySeries(drawPoints = FALSE, pointShape = "square", color = "blue") %>% 
   dyRangeSelector(dateWindow = c("2018-04-01", "2019-04-01"))

Informacion adicional.
> str(base1)
 Time-Series [1:43, 1] from 2016 to 2019: 100 100 100 98.9 99.8 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr "Cumplimiento"

> str(x)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   43 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Mes y año   : chr  "2015-10-01" "2015-11-01" "2015-12-01" "2016-01-01" ...
 $ Cumplimiento: num  100 100 100 98.9 99.8 ...
>
```

Comment: Bienvenido JRN a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Por favor, añade a tu pregunta la estructura de `x`  pegando la salida de `str(x)`, gracias.

Comment: Hola @PatricioMoracho, adjunto la informacion. Gracias.

Comment: Un posible problema es esto `x[nrow(x)-12,1]`, si tienes 12 períodos o la selección es únicamente del primer año te va a retornar una cadena vacía, en todo caso para ir 12 meses para atrás, debes hacer `x[nrow(x)-11,1]`. Estos valores debieran ser totalmente usables así `dyRangeSelector(dateWindow = c(x[nrow(x)-11,1], x[nrow(x),1]))`

Comment: @PatricioMoracho a mi tambien me parece que deberia funcionar sin embargo por alguna razon donde deberia aparecer el grafico aparece en blanco y al cambiar `dyRangeSelector(dateWindow = c(x[nrow(x)-11,1], x[nrow(x),1]))`  por `dyRangeSelector(dateWindow = c("2018-04-01", "2019-04-01"))` me vuelve a aparecer el grafico.

Comment: Es muy raro, no llego a ver dónde puede estar el problema. Cuando dices en blanco, ¿significa totalmente en blanco o te muestra los ejes pero sin mostrar ninguna linea?

Comment: Totalmente en blanco sin ejes, ni lineas ni nada, ademas estoy trabajando en flexdashboards por lo que desidí correrlo en la consola normal de rstudio y me salio este mensaje:
´Input to asJSON(keep_vec_names=TRUE) is a named vector. In a future version of jsonlite, this option will not be supported, and named vectors will be translated into arrays instead of objects. If you want JSON object output, please use a named list instead. See ?toJSON.´

Comment: @PatricioMoracho de casualidad sabe que significa ese mensaje que mostre arriba?

Comment: Eso parece simplemente una advertencia de shinny, posiblemente este esperando algún lista que sea del tipo `named list` (con nombre en cada elemento). Algunas recomendaciones que podría hacerte 1) Intenta reproducir el gráfico por afuera de `shinny` ¿funciona? 2) Actualiza los paquetes que este usando 3) Ejecuta todo en una sesión limpia de R, asegurate que entorno global este limpio.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho ok, voy a probar esas recomendaciones, muchas gracias por su tiempo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo com algunas funciones de `zoo`. La idea es convertir la clase `ts` que tienes para la clase `Date`, y funciona.

```
Nm=100 # para simular otro numero de meses
base2=ts(frequency = 12, start = c(2015, 10),runif(Nm,90,100))
library(zoo)
index(as.zoo(base2))
ds=as.Date(as.yearmon(index(as.zoo(base2)),"%mmm %Y"), frac = 0)
ds[c(length(ds)-12,length(ds))]

dygraph(base2) %>%
  dyAxis("y", label = "Y", valueRange = c(50, 110)) %>%
  dyAxis("x", label = "X", drawGrid = FALSE) %>% 
  dySeries(drawPoints = FALSE, pointShape = "square", color = "blue") %>% 
  dyRangeSelector(dateWindow = ds[c(length(ds)-12,length(ds))])
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: amigo, exactamente eso es y el grafico funciona como esperaba, muchisimas gracias!